# Focus problem when Ajax call for multiple fields calling the same callback function

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have implemented a custom form. I put same Ajax callback function for multiple field. When one Ajax call completes, I click on other field. But I can't unfocused previous field. Sometimes the Ajax call runs for multiple field.

My code:

```
$form['worklocation'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Work Location'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',

   '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'advance_search_autocomplete_callback.advancesearch_autocomplete_callback',
    '#autocomplete_route_parameters' => array('type' => 'worklocation'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => [$this, 'friends_advance_search_results'],
    ),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('form-control')),

  );

  $form['school'] = array(
    '#title' => t('School'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',

    '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'advance_search_autocomplete_callback.advancesearch_autocomplete_callback',
    '#autocomplete_route_parameters' => array('type' => 'school'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => [$this, 'friends_advance_search_results'],
    ),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('form-control')),

  );
  $form['college'] = array(
    '#title' => t('College / University'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',

   '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'advance_search_autocomplete_callback.advancesearch_autocomplete_callback',
    '#autocomplete_route_parameters' => array('type' => 'college'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => [$this, 'friends_advance_search_results'],
    ),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('form-control')),

  );
```

Callbakck:

```
function friends_advance_search_results(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

 $search_result = array(
                    '#theme' => 'friends_advanced_search_list',
                    '#friends' => $friends_list,
                    '#info' => array('display' => 'hide', 'friend_recommend' => 0, 'load_more' => $load_more, 'no_results' => 1,'search_action' => 1),

                    );

   $output = render($search_result);
   $id = '#advanced-friend-list';
   $response = new AjaxResponse();
   $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand($id, $output)); 

   return $response; 

}
```

Problem:
[image]

Comment: And what happens when you use different functions for every callback?

Comment: `'#ajax' => [
  'callback' => [$this, 'friends_advance_search_results'],
  'disable-refocus' => TRUE,
],`  I missed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable `disable-refocus` when adding the ajax callback:

```
'#ajax' => [
  'callback' => [$this, 'friends_advance_search_results'],
  'disable-refocus' => TRUE,
],
```

See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2627788

Comment: It's also possible to set it in attributes : '#attributes' => [
            'data-disable-refocus' => 'true',
          ],